# Is there a preview mode for shopware 6 apps?

Tags: shopware6

is there a built-in solution for shopware 6 apps to be previewed? For example my app shows messages and I want the shop owner to see the messages in a preview before he activates the messages globally in the shop. How do I obtain this functionality?
Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing out of the box. If the preview doesn't have to be behind an authentication and may just broadly be hidden, then you could use a query parameter to decide on showing the message, even if the general display is turned off.

```html
{% if config('MyApp.config.globallyActive') or app.request.query.has('previewEnabled') %}
   <p>My Message visible if globally active or preview is enabled</p>
{% endif %}
```

Then inform the shop owner to visit a page where a message would be shown using the `previewEnabled` query parameters:
`http://shop.example.tld/some-page-with-the-message?previewEnabled`

Comment: Thank your very much. This is a very good idea. So basically if the preview mode is active, everyone can access it by knowing to add a query parameter. I think I go for it. Cheers!